# Работа с com в JS

Tags: javascript, com-port

Иногда все работает корректно, а иногда считывается только один символ. При отправке данных с сенсора используется первый символ '$', а при отправки сообщения в консоль используется первый символ '*', сообщение принимается в течении секунды. И при отправке сообщения "*hello" получается иногда вывод "hello", иногда "h", а иногда просто ничего. Сообщение в com-port отправляется целиком, увеличение задержки (millis() - t) не помогает.

```
if(myPort.available() > 0)
{
  char s = char(myPort.read());

  print("Master char : ", s);

  if(s == '$')
    readSensData();

  else if(s == '*')
  {  
    long t = millis();

    print("Data received : ");

    while(millis() - t < 1000)    
      if(myPort.available() > 0)
        print(char(myPort.read()));
   println();
  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При чем здесь javascript?

Comment: Порт не гарантирует, что всё принятое придёт одной целой посылкой. Принятые данные нужно складывать вместе и разбирать.